# Browser network has large latency when a websocket connection is alive

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, websocket

I have a web application that uses websockets and jquery.
When a websocket connection is alive, all other network actions start having a big latency.

Screenshot at [here](http://flic.kr/p/jnKUfD)

eg.
web app accesses same server with different uri. `/setup` is a web socket connection; this connection stays in the pending state.
`/env` is a jquery ajax call (async), and has 31.07s latency.
I used wireshark to monitor, and found out that the server response is fine. The response packet arrives at the client quickly, but the browser itself seems to get it very late.
I tried with Chrome 32.0.1700.76m and with IE8, but both have the same problem.

Comment: Can you show some code? It is very difficult to know what is going on. The problem might as well be in your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I answered you in comments.**

Check your websocket 'onopen' and 'onmessage' events. If your code is always executing websocket events then there may be some problems with executing the main code where you send the ajax frame.

Comment: The server send a heartbeat packet every 5s, and 'onmessage' handle it by return directly. But network still have large latency even when  setting heartbeat interval to 60s.

Comment: The similar problem accures if the ajax request has the header 'Connection: keep-alive'. Try to set the header 'Connection: close' for your ajax connection.

Comment: thanks for the clues, I found where the problem is when I checked the response header. There is no 'Content-Length' field in the header, I think the brower just doesn't known when to finish receive until timeout. So I add 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked ' to the header and everything is fine.